# Simply type to search in the default KDE Desktop/Activity

Tags: kde, desktop, desktop-environment

In KDE, one can create new [Activities](http://www.datamation.com/open-source/the-mystery-of-kde-activities-1.html), which are a sort of different types of Desktops (sets of workspaces) with specific characteristics:

[image]

To specify each activity there are various options.

Clicking the last option of the menu that opens when right-clicking the desktop, one can switch between different 'Layouts':

[image]

There a 6 different layouts - each representing a very different type of desktop:

[image]

Changing the layout in this way is possible for the Activities that are already in place.

But when you create new activities, there is a different set of options available, called 'Templates'.

[image]

One of these is called **'Search and launch': it allows to search (for an application etc) just by starting to type (typing opens the search window) without any other preliminary action like clicking the menu launcher button or using a shortcut to show the search window**.

Can this feature be enabled within the main desktop (the default one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The "Search and launch" template coincides with the "Default desktop" layout. So, just change the layout of your main desktop (which means the layout of the entire *Activity*) to "Default desktop" (the fifth entry in the list of layouts)  in order to enable the "just-type-to-search" feature inside that activity.
- There is no "default" or main Activity per se. Also, any Activity can be deleted, including the default one, from within a different Activity. If you have enabled the 'Search and launch' template in a new Activity, nothing stops that from becoming the main one.